# Are comments allowed on the same line as preprocessor directives and what is their meaning in such case?

Tags: c++, comments, preprocessor-directive

I am thinking about something like this:

```
#include <iostream> // Comment
```

Well, cppreference.com ( http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/preprocessor ) claims that:

> The preprocessing directives control the behavior of the preprocessor. Each directive occupies one line and has the following format:
>
> # character
>      preprocessing instruction (one of define, undef, include, if, ifdef, ifndef, else, elif, endif, line, error, pragma)
>      arguments (depends on the instruction)
>      line break

So well, a complete specification for the entire line is given, and there's no place for a comment there. Suggesting comments are disallowed on such lines.

However, both g++ and clang++ accept such intput even with -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic. Also cplusplus.com provides examples of such comments: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/operator%3E%3E/

I am even more confused by the fact that somebody told me that "*It's still valid to put comments in # lines, but they might not mean what you want*". I'm not sure how this could be the case, since according to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases comments are replaced by space characters before the preprocessor is launched – so if they are allowed on # lines, how could they interfere with the semantics of such a # line?

Answer (score 17):

As stated in the translation phases document you linked to: Comments are replaced with a space in step 3 of phase 3. The preprocessor is executed in phase 4.

So by the time the preprocessor processes `#` lines, comments have been turned into whitespace, which generally have no impact on the behavior of the preprocessing directives.